# The error shows even after CLI is upgraded- The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular

I have tried updating the cli version and below is the details:
After this also i can see the error. The npm install, cache clean or build doesnot work.

```
 Angular CLI: 8.3.17
 Node: 10.16.3
 OS: win32 x64
 Angular: 8.2.13
 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
 ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
 ... router

 Package                           Version
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 @angular-devkit/architect         0.803.17
 @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.17
 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.17
 @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.17
 @angular-devkit/core              8.1.1
 @angular-devkit/schematics        0.4.2
 @angular/cli                      8.3.17
 @angular/http                     4.4.7
 @ngtools/json-schema              1.1.0
 @ngtools/webpack                  8.3.17
 @schematics/angular               8.3.17
 @schematics/update                0.803.17
 rxjs                              6.5.3
 typescript                        3.5.3
 webpack                           4.35.3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you are running the command in the project root folder.

Comment: You must set your directory - where your package.json file is located. then you can serve your application

Answer (score 1):

Always remember you need to be in you application directory while running ng serve like

```
D:\>project\firstapp>ng server
```

if you will be doing like the bellow one then you will get the error you are getting as of noe

```
D:\>project>ng server
```

So always run the ng serve command in app folder
Thanks